# Extract specific values from JSON array

Tags: json, delphi

I have a JSON response that is formatted this way:

```
- Client 1
  - Date: 15.07.2017
  - Name: John
  - URL: www.google.com
- Client 2
  - Date: 15.07.2017
  - Name: Jane
  - URL: www.google.com
- Client N...
```

How could I extract only the Name & URL value from each client so I could add them to a listbox for example? Also please note that "Client 1" could be named otherwise, like "User 1" or just "1", that's not important, but the code should extract the values regardless of the parent object name.

**PS:** Sorry for missleading, the JSON format above was pseudo-code from memory, the actual format is:

```
[
  {
    "date":"xxx", 
    "name":"xxx", 
    "url":"xxx"
  }, 
  {
    "date":"xxx", 
    "name":"xxx", 
    "url":"xxx"
  }, 
  {
    "date":"xxx", 
    "name":"xxx", 
    "url":"xxx"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is not related to Firemonkey. JSON libraries are framework independent. There are countless questions here about parsing json. Choose a library. Read its documentation. This is programming 101, doing basic research.

Comment: That isn't JSON format. We have no idea how the actual JSON looks. Is it a named array inside an object? Or is the whole content an array of objects? How is `Client 1`, for example, located in the JSON data? Since objects in an array have no name, where does this come from? Could it be that you actually have an object containing named objects?  We would need to see the *real*, *actual* JSON to know how to parse it. Even then, as David said, there are endless resources out there for you.

Comment: @JerryDodge: it looks like YAML, which can easily be converted to JSON though.

Comment: Jerry, I thought people would get the idea from pseudo-JSON so I don't have to paste an actual response... Actual JSON looks like [{"date":"xxx", "name":"xxx", "url":"xxx"}, {"date":"xxx", "name":"xxx", "url":"xxx"}, {"date":"xxx", "name":"xxx", "url":"xxx"}]

Comment: This is essentially looking for a tutorial, which is off-topic.  Consuming JSON is [easily found in the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON).

Answer (score 3):

Answer in case anybody is looking.

```
procedure Answer;
var
  JSON: string;
  ClientItem: TJSONValue;
  ClientList: TJSONArray;
  ListBoxItem: TListBoxItem;
begin
  JSON := TFile.ReadAllText('.\your-file.json');
  ClientList := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSON) as TJSONArray;
  if Assigned(ClientList) then
  try
    ListBox.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      for ClientItem in ClientList do
      begin
        ListBoxItem := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox);
        ListBoxItem.StyleLookup := 'CustomListbox';
        ListBoxItem.StylesData['URL'] := ClientItem.GetValue<string>('url');
        ListBoxItem.StylesData['Name'] := ClientItem.GetValue<string>('name');
        Listbox.AddObject(ListBoxItem);
      end;
    finally
      Listbox.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    ClientList.Free;
  end;
end;
```